# getBoundingClientRect() returns different values for svg foreignObject in the IE edge browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

Here, I am putting the paragraph in the SVG with the help of `<foreignObject>` element. Then, I want get the values of `getBoundingClientRect()`. It returns the same left, top, etc. for the Chrome and Firefox browser. But in case of IE Edge it returns different values and in IE 11, the `foreignObject` itself is not working.

JavaScipt, CSS, and HTML :

```js
var oForeignObject = document.getElementById("oForeignObject");
var oBoundingRectangle = oForeignObject.getBoundingClientRect();
var oDescription = document.getElementById("description");
oDescription.innerHTML = "left = " + oBoundingRectangle.left + " top = " + oBoundingRectangle.top;
```

```css
#oSvg {
  border : solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG ForeignObject</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id = "oSvg" width = "500" height = "300">
      <foreignObject id = "oForeignObject" x = "100" y = "100" width = "100" height = "100">
        <p style = "border : solid 1px black;">
          Hello World
        </p>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
    <div id = "description">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/ygtLz6wk/15/

Please check this link on IE edge and different browsers.

Comment: Yes their implementation seems buggy (it's like the box is moved to the bottom-right corner). But what is your question? The inner content seems to report the correct values, and getBBox seems to report the correct values too. So you might manage a workaround, but since you didn't stated what you need this for, we can't do it for you.

Comment: Report Edge bugs [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/)

Comment: @Kaiido The same code returns different top and left values in IE edge browser. That is the issue. Do I need to add anything more for IE edge browser? I want to get the getBBox values same for all browsers.